# Which option of compliance information fits my application, and if needed any compliance documents, what are the documents?

Tags: ios, flutter, encryption, standards-compliance, apple-developer

I developed Flutter applications, that implement AES-256 encryption algorithm using the encrypt package (https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt), and also that implement the PBKDF2 hash algorithm, using the conduit_password_hash package (https://pub.dev/packages/conduit_password_hash).

The main use of hash function is to hash the passphrase entered by the user for more security. An the main use of the encryption function is to encrypt/decryption the user data, so it still safe, secure, in the database, and synchronized with with other versions of our application, like the web version, or the browser extension. Also, it is to encrypt/decrypt the user key if he wants that, for an extra security layer.

I am trying to deploy my iOS and macOS applications i am asked about the compliance information.
[image: compliance information]

So, i am asking what option i need to select, and which documents are needed to upload.

As I am using standard algorithms like AES-256 and PBKDF2 hash, so, I think i need to select the second option, which is:

> Standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the encryption within Apple's operating system

However selecting this option asks me, if the application will be distribute to France, which is yes, and then it asks for compliance documents, which i don't know, what are the documents in my case. Did I need to create them? Are they related to the packages i used ?

So, please anyone can answer my thoughts, explaining what i should select, and why ?
Also, please, if anything that needed to include concerning this, or reviewed, like any other feature that can be viewed as an encryption ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like option 2 is what you would need to select since the packages you use implement crypto in Dart (pointycastle). You will need to fill in the form [here](https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/en/regulation/cryptology/how-to-submit-an-application/) and lodge it with the French government. It would be much easier if you could find packages that simply call down to the native crypto functions on each platform.

Comment: I understand! Thank you so much for your answer, this is so much helpful!